# Alternate access mapping in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, iis

I have mapped my farm into default and internet sites. Problem is, on the internet zone, some site collections are still pointing to the default zone which cant be resolved from outside. This causes some site collections to inaccessible from outside the intranet LAN. Why is this the case? 
Can I manually force the site collection to pick the external mappings?

Answer (score 1):

AAM is not the same as URL rewriting. I usually try to appoint 1 URL for a web application as default and use that for both internal and external traffic. I use extending only for cases in which you need a different authentication provider for instance.

So try to use the URL which is resolved from outside as default and point internal users to the same address. Especially for collaboration purposes, people sending eachother links to documents, this is far more logical then using multiple URLs to get to the same stuff.

Comment: Jasper, this is already the case and most of the site collections are 'seeing' this external Public URL. I have created links to all my site collections on the intranet. The issue is, when you hover on the some site collections, the URL resolves to the internal name of the server which cannot be resolved externally. How do I force these stubborn site collections to reflect the external URL? Do I have to recreate them from scratch?

Comment: If you recreate one of them, does that solve the problem for that particular link? SharePoint should change any URLs listed as AAM to the current zone. If that works for some links, but not all, I'd say it's not recognizing the links as being AAM links. I'm not sure if a link is marked as AAM link when you save it, or if they're all being processed on a request (search & replace style).